# Download Jasper Report using PHP

Tags: php, jasper-reports

[http://localhost:8080/jasperserver/flow.html?_flowId=viewReportFlow&reportUnit=/reports/Custom/Jobs_Report&j_username=imtiaz&j_password=imtiaz&viewAsDashboardFrame=true&output=pdf] This url generates PDF file. Now I want to make an application by PHP, which can download that generated PDF file.

Comment: `file_get_contents('http://localhost:8080/jasperserver/flow.html?_flowId=viewReportFlow&reportUnit=/reports/Custom/Jobs_Report&j_username=imtiaz&j_password=imtiaz&viewAsDashboardFrame=true&output=pdf');`

Comment: I've tried this but it not shows the download pop window, I need that please.

Comment: In that case, I would suggest setting up a proxy using Apache.

Comment: Here I got the solution. Please see this link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6516902/how-to-get-response-using-curl-in-php][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6516902/how-to-get-response-using-curl-in-php

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = 'http://localhost:8080/jasperserver/flow.html?_flowId=viewReportFlow&reportUnit=/reports/Custom/Jobs_Report&j_username=imtiaz&j_password=imtiaz&viewAsDashboardFrame=true&output=pdf';
$pdf_data = file_get_contents($url);
file_put_contents(uniqid().'_download.pdf',$pdf_data);
```

EDITED:
if you need download popup dialog you need to add pdf header

```
header("Content-type:application/pdf");
header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename='downloaded.pdf'");
```