# on curl "connect.stripe.com/oauth/token" it will get no response

Tags: php, curl, stripe-payments

https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=ca_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&scope=read_write

from the above mentioned api I get the code.

```
$code = $_GET['code'];
```

from this code I curl this http://connect.stripe.com/oauth/token but the problem is that it is not getting any response

```
     echo $code;

$token_request_body = array(
    'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
    'client_id' => 'ca_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'code' => $code,
    'client_secret' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
);

define("TOKEN_URI", "http://connect.stripe.com/oauth/token");

$req = curl_init(TOKEN_URI);
curl_setopt($req, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($req, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($req, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($token_request_body));

// TODO: Additional error handling
$respCode = curl_getinfo($req, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
echo $respCode;
$resp = json_decode(curl_exec($req), true);
echo $resp;
curl_close($req);

echo $resp['access_token'];
```

Comment: use curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); and check

Comment: did 1 mean something else ?? I used true as third parameter.. so both are same or not??

Comment: @satishrajak It didnt work, I changed it to 1

Comment: take reference from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6516902/how-to-get-response-using-curl-in-php

Comment: @satishrajak I dont think its the problem of how to curl request as I have used curl many times, the issue is with the stripe api I guess, am i calling it right, the code executes completely

Comment: this is the site https://stripe.com/docs/connect/standalone-accounts where I get this code

Answer (score 0):

Your code sends the `code` to the endpoint over plain HTTP which is something that is forbidden by spec and the server should not return the tokens. The example code at stripe.com also shows an HTTPs URL. Switch:

```
define("TOKEN_URI", "http://connect.stripe.com/oauth/token");
```

to:

```
define("TOKEN_URI", "https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/token");
```

FWIW: the plain HTTP URL actually redirects to HTTPs which is something your client doesn't handle, and it shouldn't since it would be insecure and a violation of the spec.