# how to check proper url before request from postman

Tags: php, api, http

```
 $url = 'http://sfs.dev.pankaj.happlabs.in/api/v1/init';
```

If file name init doesn't exist and whole  url is correct how to check that in php.

Comment: Check the response?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get response using cURL in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6516902/how-to-get-response-using-curl-in-php)

Comment: Well, if your API is coded properly, you should receive a 401 or at least a 404 status code back. That should be info enough right?

Comment: Unless you cache the whole site there's no way to determine if that URL is "proper" before a request.

Comment: IsThisJavascript that isn't true!

Comment: Really @delboy1978uk ? I'm generally intrigued. I was under the impression that by "propper" `init` is not correct but something like `initialize` would be, therefore, without all that cached the OP would not be able to determine if the link is valid before sending a request

Comment: Have you heard about google.com ?

Comment: well maybe not 'before' a request (having reread you), but there are plenty of ways to check an endpoint

Comment: Yes, I should probably have added more info in my first comment haha

Answer (score 1):

The JSON at http://sfs.dev.pankaj.happlabs.in/api/v1/init is invalid, so you will get errors. The endpoint appears to be correct though.

To check in PHP however (to answer your question), you can use :

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

```
<?php 

if ($html = file_get_contents('http://cia.gov')) {
    // $html has content
}
```